# Not able to find java

Tags: java

I am not able to check my java home.

- The `/etc/environment` file is empty.
- Nothing is mentioned in
  `.bashrc`.
- `rpm -qa | grep java` prints nothing.
- `java -version` says "Java command not found".

However, java is running on the machine:-

> 00:00:38 /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -Dproc_datanode -Xmx1024m -Dhdp.version=2.6.1.0-129 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhdp.version= -java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhdp.version= -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop/hdfs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=hdfs -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=:/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhdp.version=2.6.1.0-129 -Dhadoop.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop/hdfs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop-hdfs-datanode-asokpronode1.openstacklocal.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=hdfs -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Djava.library.path=:/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -server -server -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:NewSize=200m -XX:MaxNewSize=200m -Xloggc:/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/gc.log-201802211556 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,DRFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,DRFAAUDIT -server -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:NewSize=200m -XX:MaxNewSize=200m -Xloggc:/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/gc.log-201802211556 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,DRFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,DRFAAUDIT -server -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:NewSize=200m -XX:MaxNewSize=200m -Xloggc:/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/gc.log-201802211556 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,DRFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,DRFAAUDIT -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode

Comment: Looks pretty clear from that *exactly* where `java` is.

Comment: @tadman Can you point that to me please? Is it /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java ? Why can't I run java -version or get an output for rpm -qa | grep java

Comment: It's not in your `PATH`, but you've found it, just answered your own question there. If it's not in your `PATH` environment variable then you need to specify the full path to the executable each time.